# Change name of CSS in Yii2

Tags: css, yii2

I want to change the name of the css-file in Yii2 from site.css to site.css.php.
But I can't find the file where the css-file is included.
I have especially searched in main.php, but there is no link to the css.

Comment: What the reason of doing this? $css property of AssetBundle is designed to register css files, not php. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$css-detail

Comment: I want to use php in my css to generate random color

Comment: Rechecked it, it's possible to use php there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it. It is in assets -> AppAsset.php